# React Deployment in Azure DevOps

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

When i try to navigate to a particular route or page the app says "**The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**" and also the fonts are not loaded, Only the initial page is loaded no other navigation is happening. Can anyone help me out?
[Font not loaded and the path font after npm run build is static/media/font_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/190Cy.png)

Comment: Share your code

Comment: How is your deploying your code? is there some server which is hosting your app or some file system like AWS S3/Azure Blob

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I deployed the code in azure release once the pipeline is built

Comment: Provide the detail build and release log here. We will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a web.config file in your public folder to implement client side routing. React uses client side routing and your server should know to allow that.

**Add a web.config file in your public directory with the content below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Assets" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

create .htaccess file in public folder with the below code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^[^\.]+$" "index.html"
```

Comment: Thanks @Sankhavaram, i used the xml file but it still doesn't work and im using Node runtime.

Comment: @Anil even if its node, you got to add .htaccess file as well. I am using Node evironment though! Make sure you redeploy the code once you add both the files.

Comment: @Shankhavaram i'm new to in deploying react app using azure devops, so can you help me from the begining?

Comment: @AnilPrasad Did you get any issue during deployment using azure devops? Please check the blog and follow the steps there: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/deploying-react-apps-to-azure-with-azure-devops/

Comment: @AnilPrasad Have you checked the blog https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/deploying-react-apps-to-azure-with-azure-devops/? Is it helpful?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Yes thanks for the support it is working now